Covariance of a multivariate autoregression
Consider an autoregressive process of the form,
$$
x_{t+1} = Ax_t + \xi_t,
$$
where $\xi_t$ is sampled from ${N}(0,\Sigma)$, then I have two formulas from the stationary covariance that do not agree.
In the first case, I can consider,
$$E[x_{t+1}x^T_{t+1}] = E[(Ax_t + \xi_t)(Ax_t + \xi_t)^T]\\
=AE[x_tx^T_t]A^T + AE[x_t\xi^T_t] + E[\xi_tx^T_t]A + E[\xi_t\xi^T_t]\\
= AE[x_tx^T_t]A^T + \Sigma,
$$
which, assuming the process is stationary, means that steady state covariance satisfies,
$$
S = ASA^T + \Sigma.
$$
Alternatively, I can say that the covariance after $t$ steps is given by,
$$
S(t) = A^tS(0)(A^{T})^t + \sum_{s=1}^t A^s\Sigma(A^{T})^s,
$$
which instead satisfies the relationship,
$$
S(t+1) = A(S(t)+\Sigma)A^T,
$$
which at stationarity becomes,
$$
S = A(S+\Sigma)A^.
$$
These cannot both be true unless,
$$
A\Sigma A^T = \Sigma,
$$
and I see no reason why this, in general, holds.
Could you help me find which of these is correct and where the mistake is?

$x_{t+1} = A x_{t} + \xi_t$ so
$var(x_{t+1}) = A  var(x_{t}) A^{\prime}  + \Sigma_t + 2 \times  cov( A x_{t}, \Sigma)$
The last term is zero so one if left with
$var(x_{t+1}) = A var(x_{t}) A^{\prime} + \Sigma_t$
So, that's the relation once the t-subscripts are removed so the first one is correct.  I'm not sure how you came up with the second relation but it's an equality rather than a sum so they don't add. I hope this helps.

$X\sim AX+\xi$ implies that $S=E(XX^T)=ASA^T+\Sigma$. Iterating once:
$X\sim A(AX+\xi)+\xi_1$ implies $S=A^2S(A^T)^2+ A\Sigma A^T+\Sigma. $ No contradiction with $S=ASA^T+\Sigma$

Thanks Letac Gerard . I didn't notice that they were the same thing.
